# How to Interpret These Examples According to Fuctional Dependency in Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, functional-dependencies

I'm leraning the concept of functional dependency in databse desing and I came to the following examples which have confused me.

```
1. {State, Driver_Licence_Number} -> SSN
2. Phone# -> Address and Address -> ZipCode, then Phone# -> ZipCode
```

What I have learned is that `X -> Y` means X **functinally dertermins** Y or in other words Y is **functionally dependant** on X.

But I find the examples above contradictory to this defenition. For example How does the State and the Driver_Licence_Number determine the SSN? Or My phone number depends on the place where I live (county code, area code) so shuldn't it be Address -> Phone#? (or ZipCode -> Phone#).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at functional dependency in two different ways, depending on whether you are building a new database or analysing one that's already built.

For a new database, you discover the functional dependencies in the subject matter, and then use them to guide your database design, specifically with regard to table composition and data normalization.

For an existing database you try to discover the functional dependencies that may have guided the designer.  You might use existing data, although this can be misleading.  You might also use database constraints, or application code, or data documentation such as a data dictionary, if there is one.

Turning to the state and driver's license number case, here's how I look at the subject matter.  In the real world, state and driver's license number determine a single individual.  A single individual has only one SSN.  Therefore, state plus driver's license number determines SSN.

This is assuming that things are not screwed up, and that the Social Security Administration has not mistakenly assigned more than one SSN to one individual.  Also that the department of motor vehicles has not screwed up, and accepted a fraudulent SSN in the process of granting a license to a person.

A different person looking at the same subject matter might see things differently.

If you accept the above, and you find a table that contains State, LicenseNo, and SSN as columns, but State and LicenseNo are not a candidate key,  then the table is not in BCNF.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have learned is that X -> Y means X functionally determines Y or in other words Y is functionally dependant on X.

That is not a definition of functional dependency, it is a definition of "->".

*Functionally determines* has a precise technical meaning:

We say that a set of columns S functionally determines another set T in a table when each subrow for the first always appears with the same subrow for the second. We write S -> T and say S is the determinant set and T is the determined set. We call S -> T a functional dependency (FD). When S is a superset of T we say it is a trivial FD. When A is a column in T we say S functionally determines A.

Functional dependency is not about "how" things are "determined" in the world but about what values can turn up in a particular table. That is a consequence of what rows you are supposed to put in the table given a situation and what situations can come up. (Each table has a DBA-given parameterized statement called a *predicate*. The parameters of the predicate are the columns of the table. A table holds the rows that make a true statement from its predicate.) Which is in turn of course affected by how things are "determined" in the world.

> ```
> 1. {State, Driver_Licence_Number} -> SSN
> ```

This says that every particular `State`-`Driver_Licence_Number` subtuple value in the table appears with the same particular `SSN` value. If these table columns have the obvious meanings then this could be because a state and a driver's licence number identify a particular person and every person has a single SSN. Or maybe because people don't always have an SSN or just one SSN, but the states, drivers license numbers and SSNs are of employees of a particular company and a person has to have given them exactly one SSN to be employed there. Note how whether a FD holds depends on both the table's predicate and what table values can arise from applying that predicate to situations that can arise.

> ```
> 2. Phone# -> Address and Address -> ZipCode, then Phone# -> ZipCode
> ```

The first FD says that a particular `Phone#` always appears with the same `Address` in this particular table. Maybe because this table holds rows that make predicate "... AND phone number *Phone#* is billed at address *Address* AND ..." true. Maybe the table is a reverse directory of phone numbers giving the main address of the one employee that it is assigned to.

But *given* that the first two FDs hold, the third *must* hold. If there is only one `Address` per `Phone#` and only one `ZipCode` per `Address` then there can only be one `ZipCode` per `Phone#`. There are a few rules called *Armstrong's axioms* that allow us to derive all FDs that hold as a consequence of given ones holding.